# AGPL alternatives for commercial software

Tags: licensing, open-source, agpl, open-close

Are there any *real* alternatives (i.e. non-customized software license agreement) to the AGPL license if you want to share your source code **and** make money selling software licenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  The GPL.

There are many companies that make money by providing services and support for an open-source project.  The GPL insures that no other company can take the code private and turn it into a proprietary application.

You can also go with a Dual-Licensing model, [like Sencha does](https://www.sencha.com/legal/).  The motivation for paying for a commercial license is that you don't have to open-source your own code.

> Sencha Ext JS is made available under Commercial License or the GNU General Public License version 3 (GPLv3). The Commercial License requires the payment of a fee for each Designated User (i.e. developer). If you choose not to pay a fee and use the GPLv3 license, you are required to release the source code of any program that you distribute that uses Ext JS. If you choose to pay for a Commercial License, you are not required to disclose your source code.

Comment: I can sell *services* with GPL, but can I sell licenses for the software also? I heard otherwise you see.

Comment: The GPL doesn't have anything to say about whether or not you can charge for GPL'd software, or how much you can charge.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: This is ridiculous. It's your eff…ing software, you can do whatever the eff… you want with it. The lengths to which anti-open-source FUD has brainwashed developers into thinking that Richard Stallman tries to steal their software is truly ridiculous. See http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney and http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq#DoesTheGPLAllowDownloadFee and http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq#DoesTheGPLRequireAvailabilityToPublic and most importantly http://gnu.org/philosophy/selling as well as https://opensource.org/osd-annotated (article 1).

Comment: In short: yes, the GPL allows selling software, but that is irrelevant anyway, because *you* are *giving* the license, not *receiving* it, so you aren't bound it anyway: it's your software, you don't need a license in order to be allowed to do something with it.